# Methods of user authentication for learning disabled users

Tags: java, android, ios, mobile, accessibility

Apologies if this has been asked before.

**I am currently looking into user authentication methods for learning disabled users with special educational needs. Users will be logging into a mobile app and require authentication due to sensitive family issues.**

Are there known best practises for this demographic of user? It is very difficult to find anything online in relation to this. I have seen a lot of content for visually and hearing imnpaired users but it is not what I am looking for.

Assumptions I DO NOT wish to make:
Users already have Facebook or other social media accounts.
Users regularly access an email account.
Users can remember passwords with existing best practise criteria e.g. at least one capital letter, one number and one character that is neither a letter or a number.
Users will be able to cope with the conventional 'forgot password' process while on the move of accessing their email

Has anyone dealt in this area before? Any ideas or links to blogs, articles or scientific papers would be great. Any past experienced would also be welcomed.

I have come across this site http://disabilitynetwork.org/technology/40-amazing-ipad-apps-for-the-learning-disabled/#.U4R9VfldX6I

However, like other search results, it focusses on apps that serve specific disabilities rather than with the specific issues of login for a wide spread of users.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently looking into user authentication methods for learning disabled users with special educational needs

First you need to clarify the last few words above, because it can be read as "I wanted to make sure that readers knew that people with learning disabilities had needs that often get over looked" or "I know that some sub-group of my users have specific needs."

If it is the first, I'd recommend editing it out to avoid confusion. Hopefully only people that know what they're saying would reply and/or you would know when smoke is being blown.

If it is the second, please edit the question to include the unique needs. There may be an academic paper out there, but most are behind paywalls.

That being said, you should use best practices:

- clearly define what is required
- use label tags with form elements
- it may be a good idea to use text fields instead of password type, so people don't have to second-guess themselves - or to allow users to show the pw.
- use a clean UI, no flashy stuff. Use consistent look/feel.